# How to include external modules headers when FetchContent_Declare is used?

Tags: c++, git, cmake

I want to use [modern CMake project structure convention](https://cliutils.gitlab.io/modern-cmake/chapters/basics/structure.html) in my new project to follow good practices and to be consistent with many other projects, but I'm facing problem with include path.

My directories structure looks as follows:

```
.
├── build
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── extern
│   └── CMakeLists.txt
└── src
    ├── CMakeLists.txt
    └── main.cpp
```

I want to use [FetchContent_Declare](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FetchContent.html) instead of [git submodules](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules) to manage the third-party libraries.

The *root* `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16 FATAL_ERROR)
set(ProjectName "MyApp")

project(${ProjectName})

add_subdirectory(extern)
add_subdirectory(src)
```

The *extern* `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16 FATAL_ERROR)

include(FetchContent)
FetchContent_Declare(
  extern_spdlog

  GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/gabime/spdlog.git
  GIT_TAG        v1.8.2)

FetchContent_GetProperties(extern_spdlog)
if(NOT extern_spdlog_POPULATED)
  FetchContent_Populate(extern_spdlog)
  add_subdirectory(
    ${extern_spdlog_SOURCE_DIR}
    ${extern_spdlog_BINARY_DIR}
  )
endif()
```

The *src* `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)

set(BINARY ${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME})

file(GLOB_RECURSE SOURCES LIST_DIRECTORIES true *.h *.cpp)
set(SOURCES ${SOURCES})

add_executable(${BINARY}_run ${SOURCES})

add_library(${BINARY}_lib STATIC ${SOURCES})

target_link_libraries(${BINARY}_run extern_spdlog)
```

And the `main.cpp`:

```
#include <spdlog/spdlog.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    spdlog::info("Welcome to spdlog!");
    return 0;
}
```

CMake executes and the `spdlog` library is cloned properly and can be found in the build directory at: `build/_deps/extern_spdlog-src`.

If I call `make` in the `build` directory then I get `fatal error: spdlog/spdlog.h: No such file or directory`.

How to add *include directories* for the external libraries used in the application?

Comment: The library target is wrong. It should be `spdlog` not `extern_spdlog`. I.e. the same as defined in the external project's CMake, not the name that you used in `FetchContent`.

Answer (score 2):

I was initially confused about this as well. It doesn't help that the names of the `FetchContent` targets often match the names of the imported targets. What worked for me was similar (though not identical) to what the first comment states. I used `target_link_libraries(target spdlog::spdlog)` (if you want to use the pre-compiled library or `spdlog::spdlog_header_only` if you want to use the header source only version.